# When reading HTML in R, how do I know which paragraphs come after each title?

Tags: html, r, xml2

Consider the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <p>Text A</p>
        <p>Text B</p>
        <h3>Title 2</h3>
        <p>Text C</p>
        <h3>Title 3</h3>
        <p>Text D</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I read this file in R, using `xml2` library:

```
a = read_xml('test.html',as_html=T)
h3 = xml_find_all(a,'//h3')
xml_text(h3[[2]]) # outputs 'Title 2'
p = xml_find_all(a,'//p')
xml_text(p[[3]]) # outputs 'Text C'
```

How do I know which paragraph (`p`) comes right after each title (`h3`), considering that in my real file there may be multiple paragraphs after each title, and there are hundreds of titles, and thousands of paragraphs?

EDIT

If I convert `a` to a list, I can see in RStudio where are the titles and paragraphs:

```
a = as_list(a)
```

[image: as_list(a)]

But I just can't find a way to get which list item is a `h3` and which is a `p`!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with rvest as well. Use an adjacent sibling combinator to first get a list of p tags that immediately follow an h3, then use an xpath to get the preceding h3. Wrap that in `data.frame()` and an outer `map_dfr()` to get a single DataFrame result which maps title to the immediate following paragraph.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

html <- '<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <p>Text A</p>
        <p>Text B</p>
        <h3>Title 2</h3>
        <p>Text C</p>
        <h3>Title 3</h3>
        <p>Text D</p>
    </body>
</html>'

page <- read_html(html)

df <- page %>%
  html_elements("h3 + p") %>%
  map_dfr(., ~ data.frame(
    title = .x %>% html_element(xpath = ".//preceding-sibling::h3[1]") %>% html_text(),
    para = .x %>% html_text()
  ))

print(df)
```

---

Same logic with xml2

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
library(xml2)

html <- '<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <p>Text A</p>
        <p>Text B</p>
        <h3>Title 2</h3>
        <p>Text C</p>
        <h3>Title 3</h3>
        <p>Text D</p>
    </body>
</html>'

page <- read_xml(html)

df <- page %>%
  xml_find_all(".//h3/following-sibling::p[1]") %>%
  map_dfr(., ~ data.frame(
    title = .x %>% xml_find_first(".//preceding-sibling::h3[1]") %>% xml_text(trim = T),
    para = .x %>% xml_text(trim = T)
  ))

print(df)
```

Comment: Almost a good solution, except if some paragraphs (and titles) have exactly the same text. It would be better to have the numbered index, instead of the text.

Comment: I edited the question, thinking of an approach that could be easier, but I can't make it work.

Comment: What would be used as the numbering source? Can't you simply add numbering after the fact? Or are you expecting to know which h3s by number, out of all h3s in document, have a following p tag?

Comment: Take a look at the answer I just added. Looks like it solves the problem. Thank you, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that I can convert the XML to a list, and then get the names of the `body` subobject in the list:

```
a = read_html('<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <p>Text A</p>
        <p>Text B</p>
        <h3>Title 2</h3>
        <p>Text C</p>
        <h3>Title 3</h3>
        <p>Text D</p>
    </body>
</html>')
a = as_list(a)
names(a$html$body)
 [1] ""   "h3" ""   "p"  ""   "p"  ""   "h3" ""   "p"  ""   "h3" ""   "p"  ""
```

Now I know the positions of each `h3` and `p`, and can iterate successfully through them.